# How can I change the value inside this array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, speech-recognition

so I want to make some speech recognition (using system.speech.recognition) software with some command list that can be change. So for example at first you have 2 kind of command list : "Left,Right" which when you said left or right it will do some function. But I want in this software I can change the command list whenever I want it to change, for example at the command list above I want to change word "Left" to "Up", and when I said "Up" it will doing the function that before doing by the "Left" word. This is my code :

```
Choices commands = new Choices();
GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();

public void Masokey_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { Atext.Text, Dtext.Text});
        // GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += RecEngine_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    //save_btn
    public void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        commands.Add(new string[] { Atext.Text, Dtext.Text});
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
    }

    public void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.Result.Text == Atext.Text)
        {
          PressKey(0x1E);
         }
        else if (e.Result.Text == Dtext.Text)
        {
            PressKey(0x20);
        }
    }
```

I want to change the value inside "command.Add(new string[] {Atext.Text, Dtext.Text)"

I put the command list into a textbox so when I run the software, when I want to change the command list I just need to change the word inside the textbox and when I click the save button, the command list will change. The problem is when I click the save button, the command list won't change.

Is it possible to change the value of Choices object and GrammarBuilder object?

Comment: You do only action of adding, not removing. So, it's possible that your program get the first element which is the old elements

Comment: `button35_Click` - *please* avoid this, every time you do this, a future programmer dies... Name your buttons, name linked functions, **name everything**. (Unless this actually is a button with a big `35` written on it)

Comment: @ThierryV You're right, but is that possible to change the value of Choices object and GrammarBuilder object?

Comment: @Rafalon Ah thanks, I already rename it. Before I just put some comment above it but I forget to rename it.

Comment: See the [SpeechRecognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.requestrecognizerupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There's also an example you can follow. You should use this command each time you are about to update the Recognizer Grammar. It would be a good idea to call it even the first time you add one.

Comment: I would also use [SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to complement it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify that array (probably a list) after you fill it. 
I assume `gBuilder` contains all commands that voice recognition accepts. If that is true, add all commands you will be using and in `RecEngine_SpeechRecognized` event check if they are enabled before actually triggering actions based on them.

To give you a basic example:

```
public void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    //mode could be a string or an enum variable
    if(mode.Equals("LEFT_RIGHT") && e.Result.Text == Atext.Text)
    {
      PressKey(0x1E);
     }
    else if (mode.Equals("LEFT_RIGHT") && e.Result.Text == Dtext.Text)
    {
        PressKey(0x20);
    }else if (mode.Equals("UP_DOWN") && e.Result.Text == Stext.Text)
    {
        PressKey(...);
    }else if(mode.Equals("UP_DOWN") && e.Result.Text == Wtext.Text)
    {
        PressKey(....);
    }
}
```

If your program is going to be more complex a much better approach would be creating a list of enabled commands. An example to check that implementation:

```
public void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    //enabledCommands is a list of strings (or whatever can store Atext.Text and the others)
    if(enabledCommands.Contains(e.Result.Text){ //First check if whatever command you received is enabled
      if(e.Result.Text == Atext.Text) //then check what command it is and execute it
      {
         PressKey(0x1E);
      }
    }
}
```

If your program requires that you can go further and implement a list of objects, each of which contains a command and a Boolean indicating if that command is enabled, but that's a bunch more code and probably more complex than you need it to be.

Comment: I assume it should be mode == "LEFT_RIGHT" etc... ? :)

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I haven't touched C# is a while. :D
Edit: while making that correction, i realized it should be `equals`...

Comment: @Zero Thank you for your answer. I'll try it :D